# cannot extra data from a faunaDb feild with value as a list

Tags: faunadb

I have a very simple collection in faunaDb

it is like this:-

```
data : {
field2: { }
field2: { }
field3: { }
field4: [
{}
{}
]
}
```

field 1 & field 2 can be extracted using an indexed field , ie any of the 1,2,3, field, but filed 4 always returns null
i use
`Paginate(match(index("index_name"), "searchfield")))`

is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Hey, could you add a bit more information on how that data looks like. 
I assume the data is not full of empty {}. 

Ideally we also need to know how your index definition looks like before we can answer this question :)

Comment: @BrechtDeRooms thanks for your reply, but i basically read the documentation and figured out that you can do this with indexes, ie, this was supported by default, only my created index was wrong, thanks for the reply anyway!